# "Show Annotation..." Shortcut no longer working in Eclipse 2020-12 (4.18.0)

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, ide, shortcut

The shortcut Ctrl + Alt + A is no longer working. I already set in Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys the value "Show Annotation..." to Ctrl + Alt + A. But it's still not working.
It's still possible to use Right Click in file -> Team -> Show Annotation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- make sure you have no conflicts in the bindings
  [Example: Show Annotation + Show in (SVN Annotate). You do not want this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jbj0Z.png)
- make sure the action set "SVN" is available in your view:

window -> perspective -> customize perspective. Tab: Action Set Availability. Check SVN
[Checkbox svn in action set availability](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uvvD.png)